# SSIS - Sub query getting an error

Tags: plsql, ssis-2008

I have the below script in the Source Editor in a SSIS package and I get an error. I change to a Select * and it works. I'm not sure why this is not working. It works in P/SQL. Any help would be appreciated!

This works in my package:

```
select * from Test
```

This does not work in my package (but works in PL/SQL) and I get the below error.

```
 select * from (select id, color, shape,
dense_Rank () Over (Partition By id order by id desc as SeqRank)
    ) x
```

Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Source [111]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.

Comment: Bottom line: I want to be able to extract only where Dense_rank = 1 in a SSIS Package.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach for this questions is instead of creating a subquery one could create a CTE. A CTE is compatiable with SSIS.